# What is my last row_number in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE city ='$city' LIMIT 10 ";
   $result = $db->query($sql);
```

And I show the result like this :

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
       echo $row->city;
    }
```

**The Problem :**

Mysql , will search through my database to find **10** rows which their *city* field is similar to **$city**.

so far it is OK;

But I want to know what is the exact row_number  of  the last result , which mysql selected and I echoed it ?

( I mean , consider  with that query , Mysql selected 10 rows in my database 
where row number are:

```
  FIRST  = 1
  Second  = 5
  Third  = 6
  Forth  = 7
  Fifth  = 40
  Sixth  = 41
  Seventh  = 42
  Eitghth  = 100
  Ninth  = 110
  AND **last one = 111**
```

OK?

I want to know where is place of  this  "last one"????
)

Comment: just add an incremental variable inside to loop and increment it..

Comment: You want through a query or through php ?

Comment: :(
you didnt get my quetsion:(

Comment: Rikesh 
by php of course

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a bit of a nonsense.

Comment: mysql_num_rows() returns number of rows returned.

Comment: Also, take a look at SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Answer (score 2):

MySQL databases do not have "row numbers". Rows in the database do not have an inherent order and thereby no "row number". If you select 10 rows from the database, then the last row's "number" is 10. If each row has a field with a primary id, then use that field as its "absolute row number".

Comment: So when I say this **: SELECT .... LIMIT 2,10;**
How does mysql knows what is 2? or where is 2?
isnt it a row_number?

Comment: The answer means that, there is no explicit way by which you can get the exact row number (if any) of the data page.

Comment: How is that even possible ?
when You say : LIMIT 2,10
mysql knows that 2 means this:
get through the database , find specific row which is 20th in the databse , and then chose 10 records after 20
ist that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that happens at the data page level, rather after the 10 rows have been selected; and from there mysql internally can loop through with a loop variant boundary of 2..10. If you really interested to know how internal behavior is then do some research (OR) see if you can find source code for mysql.

Comment: @andy Simple: MySQL searches through its database to find rows that match your criteria. If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause, the order in which it will retrieve them is essentially arbitrary. With an `ORDER BY` clause the results will appear in the specified order. With `LIMIT 2, 10`, it discards the first row of that result and returns the following 10, then discards the rest. The final result will be a set of 10 rows. SQL queries are instructions to filter and optionally sort a bag full of data. That bag has no inherent order.

Answer (score 1):

You could let the loop run and track values. When the loop ends, you will have the last value. Like so:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
   echo $row->city; 
   $last_city = $row->city;
}
/* use $last_city; */
```

To get the row number in the Original Table of the last resultant (here, tenth) row, you could save the data from the tenth row and then, do the following:
1. Read whole table
2. Loop through the records, checking them against the saved data
3. Break loop as soon as data found.
Like So:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
 echo $row->city; 
 $last_row = $row;
}
```

Now, rerun the query without filters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$rowNumber = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  if($row == $last_row) break;
  $rowNumber++;
}
/* use $rowNumber */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want this :(
Consider this:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors LIMIT 3,10",
I want to know, where is placed ,  that "3"?
how mysql knows that"3" is where?

Comment: When you use `Limit X,Y`, X is the starting point (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration (how many records to display).

Comment: AHa aha
yesss
X is the starting point , now I want to know what is the ending pont ?
OK ?
x is staring
y is duration
and z whould be the ending point
????

Comment: What you want is to know the row number of the tenth `found` row in the original table ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `$last = $row->id;` (or whatever field you want) inside your `while` loop - it will keep getting reassigned with the end result being that it contains the value of the last row.

Comment: I dont want the id
I want the row number

Comment: because If one of my Id's , is deleted already , then last id will not be the last row 
OK?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$rowIndex = 0;    
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

You'd be starting a counter at zero and detecting the total number of records retrieved.

Then, as you step through the records, you could increment your counter.

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
    $rowIndex++;

    [other code]
}
```

Inside the While Loop, you could check to see whether the rowIndex is equal to the rowCount, as in...

```
if ($rowIndex == $rowCount) {
    [your code]
}
```

I know this is a year+ late, but I completely why Andy was asking his question. I frequently need to know this information. For instance, let's say you're using PHP to echo results in a nice HTML format. Obviously, you wouldn't need to know the record result index in the case of simply starting and ending a div, because you could start the div before the loop, and close it at the end. However, knowing where you are in the result set might affect some styling decisions (e.g., adding particular classes to the first and/or last rows).

I had one case in which I used a GROUP BY query and inserted each set of records into its own tabbed card. A user could click the tabs to display each set. I wanted to know when I was building the last tab, so that I could designate it as being selected (i.e., the one with the focus). The tab was already built by the time the loop ended, so I needed to know while inside of the loop (which was more efficient than using JavaScript to change the tab's properties after the fact).